# missing separator problem that doesn't relate to text editor

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following makefile in my c++ program

```
#All Targets
all: bin/cTrace

    bin/cTrace: bin/main.o bin/agent.o bin/session.o bin/graph.o bin/tree.o
        @echo 'Building target: main'
        @echo 'Invoking: C++ Linker'
        g++ -o bin/cTrace bin/main.o bin/agent.o bin/graph.o bin/tree.o bin/session.o
        @echo 'Finished building target: main'
        @echo ' '
    
    bin/main.o: src/main.cpp
        g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -c -Iinclude -o bin/main.o src/main.cpp
    
    bin/agent.o: src/Agent.cpp
        g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -c -Iinclude -o bin/agent.o src/Agent.cpp
    
    bin/session.o: src/Session.cpp
        g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -c -Iinclude -o bin/session.o src/Session.cpp
    
    bin/graph.o: src/Graph.cpp
        g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -c -Iinclude -o bin/graph.o src/Graph.cpp
    
    bin/tree.o: src/Tree.cpp
        g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -c -Iinclude -o bin/tree.o src/Tree.cpp
```

but when I write at the terminal: `make` I get the following message:

```
'makefile:7 *** missing separator  stop'
```

I have been looking for the problem and I understand that the main cause is that the text editor may change tab to space so I check throughout all my makefile and I hadn't found any problem.

What else can cause it?

edit:
after I compile `cat -e -t -v Makefile` I  get the following result:

```
spl211@spl211:~/CLionProjects/cTrace$ cat -e -t -v makefile
#All Targets^M$
all: bin/cTrace^M$
^M$
bin/cTrace: bin/main.o bin/agent.o bin/session.o bin/graph.o bin/tree.o^M$
    @echo 'Building target: main'^M$
    @echo 'Invoking: C++ Linker'^M$
    g++ -o bin/cTrace bin/main.o bin/agent.o bin/graph.o bin/tree.o bin/session.o^M$
    @echo 'Finished building target: main'^M$
    @echo ' '^M$
^M$
bin/main.o: src/main.cpp^M$
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -c -Iinclude -o bin/main.o src/main.cpp^M$
^M$
bin/agent.o: src/Agent.cpp^M$
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -c -Iinclude -o bin/agent.o src/Agent.cpp^M$
^M$
bin/session.o: src/Session.cpp^M$
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -c -Iinclude -o bin/session.o src/Session.cpp^M$
^M$
bin/graph.o: src/Graph.cpp^M$
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -c -Iinclude -o bin/graph.o src/Graph.cpp^M$
^M$
bin/tree.o: src/Tree.cpp^M$
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -c -Iinclude -o bin/tree.o src/Tree.cpp
```

Comment: Remove one level of indentation from third line onward. It is not needed.

Comment: @Shiv in my real file I don't have that indentation. its stack overflow add it

Comment: Try `cat -e -t -v Makefile` which should have `^I` for tabs and `$` for line endings and paste the output.

Comment: @Shiv I pasted it at the quistion

Comment: You do see that `^I` is missing from the file i.e. tab characters are not present.

Comment: You say _I check throughout all my makefile and I hadn't found any problem_ but however you checked, wasn't sufficient, because it is absolutely your problem.  You don't say what editor you're using but possibly it's converting TAB to space when you save your file, so when you look at it in the editor it seems like it has a TAB but when it's saved to disk the TABs are removed.  I'd say you need to either get a better editor, or else figure out how to configure your editor to not make this change.

Comment: Or, if you're willing to write a makefile that is specific to GNU make instead of "generic make", you can use the `.RECIPEPREFIX` feature of GNU make to change the prefix character to something else other than TAB, which is easier for editors to manage.  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#index-_002eRECIPEPREFIX-_0028change-the-recipe-prefix-character_0029

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.owsiak.org/m-never-ending-story/ :)

Comment: That's funny :).  But, not the problem here.  GNU make accepts both the correct (NL) and wrong (CRNL) line endings, regardless of which system you're on.  As Shiv points out the missing `^I` in the cat output clearly shows that there are no TABs in the file.